# SQL contando dados da segunda tabela do INNER JOIN, mas não deveria?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tenho 2 tabelas:

- patrocinadores
- cotas

O que preciso fazer é verificar quantos indicados os patrocinadores tem mas só contar os usuários que tem o registro na tabela **`cotas`**. A SQL que fiz é a seguinte:

> `SELECT COUNT(*) AS quantidade_indicados, p.id_patrocinador FROM patrocinadores AS p INNER JOIN cotas AS c ON c.id_user = p.id_usuario WHERE c.status = 1 GROUP BY p.id_patrocinador`

O problema do código acima é que ele está me retornando a quantidade de linhas retornadas na tabela **`cotas`**. O usuário as vezes pode ter mais de 1 registro na tabela cotas com o status 1, mas por mais que ele tenha 500 registros com o status 1 (ativo) ele só deveria contabilizar 1.

O resultado que eu esperava era algo tipo:

```
quantidade_indicados | id_patrocinador
3                         10
```

Ou seja, o patrocinador da ID 10 tem 3 indicados ativos (os ativos são verificados na tabela cotas)

O problema é se algum dos indicados tiver 300 registros na tabela cotas com o status = 1, então ele contabiliza a quantidade_indicados como 300 e não como 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta esse ai:

```
SELECT count(id) as indicados, id_patrocinador from patrocinadores WHERE 
 id_usuario IN (SELECT id_user FROM cotas WHERE status = 1) group by 
 id_patrocinador
```

Comment: Valeu Victor. Resolveu!